# helm convert map type data into json object

Tags: json, go, yaml, kubernetes-helm, helm3

i have map data in my values.yaml

values.yaml

```
shapes:
  "FIRST SHAPE": "square"
  "SECOND SHAPE": "circle"
  "THIRD SHAPE": "triangle"
```

i need to convert this as json in my config-map. Also i need to add additional json key value attribute "FOURTH_SHAPE":"rectangle" which will not be available in values.yaml.

I want end json to be

```
{"FIRST SHAPE": "square","SECOND SHAPE": "circle","THIRD SHAPE": "triangle","FOURTH_SHAPE":"rectangle"}
```

how do i get this done? i tried toJson function and it doesn't work. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use the [toJson](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#tojson-musttojson) function annd one of the [merge variants](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dictionaries-and-dict-functions).

```
{{ merge .Values.shapes (dict "FOURTH_SHAPE" "rectangle") | toJson }}
```

If you only want to add a single value, you can also use [set](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#set).

```
{{ set .Values.shapes "FOURTH_SHAPE" "rectangle" | toJson }}
```